# boto3 publish message in SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to run a script to publish message to my sns topic. I followed the documentation and my code is this :

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sns')

response = client.publish(
    TopicArn='my topic arn',    
    Message='ptt message '
)
print("Response: {}".format(response))
```

It prints the response json, but I don't see any message in my AWS SNS console. I have a lambda function which is pretty basic as a subscriber to this sns.

The lambda code :

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
         'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!') 
    }
```

How can I be sure that my message "ptt message" has been published successfully? How can I check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing of integration you can configure Delivery status logging for your SNS topic. There is a simple setting for this in GUI of SNS. This will export to CloudWatch the logs of your subscription triggers.

Secondly, your Lambda is not doing anything with the event, so your "ptt message stays in the "event" dictionary. You can for example log your event and see the structure where the actual message body comes.

```
import logging

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logging.info(event)
    ...
```

And simply to see that the Lambda was triggered by the subscription, you can open the CloudWatch Logs, find the LogGroup automatically created by AWS for your Lambda (has the name of the function in it) and search the Log Group. There are comfortable filters by *"last X minutes"*.

In order to test this integration you can also publish test messages to SNS Topic from the web interface if this feels more convenient than running a script.

Comment: So I selected my subscriber lambda function from Cloudwatch logs and saw that the lambda has been invoked everytime whenever I publish message. That's a relief. I added `logging.info(event)` inside my lambda. Is this lambda function is supposed to show event log everytime by getting triggered whenever I publish message? Or I have to run this function on my own?

Comment: Reading the documentation, what I got that the subscriber Lambda is going to be triggered on its own and show the logging info or any other print message inside it, whenever I publish message on it. Am I right?

Comment: You are right! The Log doesn't care who and how invoked the Lambda: some trigger (e.g. SNS), or web interface, or `boto3` call, or any other event. In the log you will see all the data. Just keep in mind that you need to search the whole `LogGroup`, not any specific `LogStream`. Stream represents a Lambda container where your function is executed, but it is managed by AWS so you never (almost never) know where exactly you function will run. And any change in code (new version) automatically spawns new container(s) on first call(s).